# Can these complicated expressions be simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have two very long expressions:

$$
 \left(\frac{ \left(\sin(β) \left(r_p \left(β + \frac{2}{Z} C \tan(α)\right) - V \tan(α) + r_f + N m \frac{π}{2}\right)\\
 + \cos(β) (r_f (\tan(α) + \sec(α)) + r_d - r_p)\right) r_f (\tan(α) + \sec(α))}{\sqrt{(\cos(β) \left(r_p \left(β + \frac{2}{Z} C \tan(α)\right) - V \tan(α) + r_f + N m \frac{π}{2}\right)\\
 - \sin(β) (r_f (\tan(α) + \sec(α)) + r_d - r_p))^2 + (\sin(β) \left(r_p \left(β + \frac{2}{Z} C \tan(α)\right) - V \tan(α) + r_f + N m \frac{π}{2}\right)\\
 + \cos(β) (r_f (\tan(α) + \sec(α)) + r_d - r_p))^2}}\right)\\
 + \sin(β) \left(r_p \left(β + \frac{2}{Z} C \tan(α)\right) - V \tan(α) + r_f + N m \frac{π}{2}\right)\\
 + \cos(β) (r_f (\tan(α) + \sec(α)) + r_d)
$$

and

$$
 \left(\frac{-\left(\cos(β) \left(r_p \left(β + \frac{2}{Z} C \tan(α)\right) - V \tan(α) + r_f + N m \frac{π}{2}\right)\\
 - \sin(β) (r_f (\tan(α) + \sec(α)) + r_d - r_p)\right) r_f (\tan(α) + \sec(α))}{\sqrt{(\cos(β) \left(r_p \left(β + \frac{2}{Z} C \tan(α)\right) - V \tan(α) + r_f + N m \frac{π}{2}\right)\\
 - \sin(β) (r_f (\tan(α) + \sec(α)) + r_d - r_p))^2 + (\sin(β) \left(r_p \left(β + \frac{2}{Z} C \tan(α)\right) - V \tan(α) + r_f + N m \frac{π}{2}\right)\\
 + \cos(β) (r_f (\tan(α) + \sec(α)) + r_d - r_p))^2}}\right)\\
 - \cos(β) \left(r_p \left(β + \frac{2}{Z} C \tan(α)\right) - V \tan(α) + r_f + N m \frac{π}{2}\right)\\
 + \sin(β) (r_f (\tan(α) + \sec(α)) + r_d)
$$

**Can they be simplified any?**

I've tried the `FullSimplify[]` command in WolframScript, but it doesn't reduce them at all. However, I know from previous experience that WolframScript often misses simplification opportunities, so I don't take that as proof that my expressions are stuck as-is.

**UPDATE**

Setting $P = r_p \left(β + \frac{2}{Z} C \tan(α)\right) - V \tan(α) + r_f + N m \frac{π}{2}$ and $Q = r_f (\tan(α) + \sec(α)) + r_d - r_p$, the expressions become
$$
 \left(\frac{ \left(\sin(β) P + \cos(β) Q\right) (Q - r_d + r_p)}
 {\sqrt{(\cos(β) P - \sin(β) Q)^2 + (\sin(β) P + \cos(β) Q)^2}}\right)\\
 + \sin(β) P + \cos(β) Q + \cos(β) r_p
$$
and
$$
 \left(\frac{-\left(\cos(β) P - \sin(β) Q\right) (Q - r_d + r_p)}
 {\sqrt{(\cos(β) P - \sin(β) Q)^2 + (\sin(β) P + \cos(β) Q)^2}}\right)\\
 - \cos(β) P + \sin(β) Q + \sin(β) r_p
$$

@Blue pointed out that $(\cos(β) P - \sin(β) Q)^2 + (\sin(β) P + \cos(β) Q)^2$ reduces to $P^2 + Q^2$, making the expressions become
$$
 \left(\frac{ \left(\sin(β) P + \cos(β) Q\right) (Q - r_d + r_p)}
 {\sqrt{P^2 + Q^2}}\right) + \sin(β) P + \cos(β) Q + \cos(β) r_p
$$
and
$$
 \left(\frac{-\left(\cos(β) P - \sin(β) Q\right) (Q - r_d + r_p)}
 {\sqrt{P^2 + Q^2}}\right) - \cos(β) P + \sin(β) Q + \sin(β) r_p
$$

That helps a bunch, but I'm still looking to see if I can cancel additional terms after removing the P & Q substitutions.

Comment: The chunk $(\sin\beta (r_p (\beta + 2 C \frac{\tan\alpha}{Z}) - V \tan\alpha + r_f + N m \frac{\pi}{2})$ appears three times in the first expression. There are other similar chunks. Albeit this is a masterpiece of typesetting it is not the most economic way of doing it and makes it hard to see further simplifications if there are any.

Comment: Extending the comment of @KurtG., which I definitely agree with, my first try would be to choose some consonant, such as $~S,~$ that does not appear as one of the variables.  Then, for example, I would specify $$S_1 = \sin(β) \left(r_p \left(β + 2 C \frac{\tan(α)}{Z}\right) - V \tan(α) + r_f + N m \frac{π}{2}\right).$$  I would try to identify other *repeated* chunks, and label them $S_2, S_3, \cdots.$  Then, having *simplified* the expression into one using that uses the $~S_i~$ variables as much as possible, I would look for relationships among $~S_1, S_2, S_3, \cdots.$

Comment: With appropriate choice of chunks $P$ and $Q$, the expression under the square root becomes $$(P\cos\beta-Q\sin\beta)^2+(P\sin\beta+Q\cos\beta)^2$$ which reduces to $P^2+Q^2$. Given that each of $P$ and $Q$ is a mishmash of symbols, I wouldn't expect $P^2+Q^2$ itself to simplify.

Comment: Thanks to the $PQ$ chunking, we now readily see that the terms immediately following a fraction match a factor of that fraction's numerator. Define $R:=\sqrt{P^2+Q^2}$ and $S:=Q+R-r_d+r_p$, so that $$S\left(\frac{P}{R}\sin b+\frac{Q}{R}\cos b\right)+r_p\cos b\qquad
-S\left(\frac{P}{R}\cos b-\frac{Q}{R}\sin b\right)+r_p\sin b
$$ Moreover, taking $\tan t:=P/Q$ (whence, $\sin t=P/R$ and $\cos t=Q/R$), we can write
$$S\cos(b-t)+r_p\cos b\qquad S\sin(b-t)+r_p\sin b$$ This reveals the simple structure of the expressions, but it sweeps a *lot* of messiness under the $P$, $Q$, $R$, $S$, $t$ rugs.