# Is it possible to define a single parametric curve that equals three other related curves for specific inputs?

Tags: geometry, curves, parametric, computational-geometry

## The Curves

I have worked out parametric equations for the curves of involute gear profiles using the seven gear parameters given in the "Background" section below. However, currently the fillet roulette curves are actually three different curves that apply in different scenarios based on the gear parameters:

### When $P < 0$,

$$
x(γ) = \left(P + \frac{Z}{2}\right) × \cos(γ - Q) + γ × \frac{Z}{2} × \sin(γ - Q)\\
 + F × \frac{P × \cos(γ - Q) + γ × \frac{Z}{2} × \sin(γ - Q)}{\sqrt{P^2 + \left(γ × \frac{Z}{2}\right)^2}},
$$
$$
y(γ) = \left(P + \frac{Z}{2}\right) × \sin(γ - Q) - γ × \frac{Z}{2} × \cos(γ - Q)\\
 + F × \frac{P × \sin(γ - Q) - γ × \frac{Z}{2} × \cos(γ - Q)}{\sqrt{P^2 + \left(γ × \frac{Z}{2}\right)^2}},
$$
$$
\frac{2}{Z} × P × \cot(α) ≤ γ ≤ 0
$$

### When $P ≟ 0$,

$$
x(γ) = \frac{Z}{2} × \cos(-Q) - F × \cos(γ - Q),
$$
$$
y(γ) = \frac{Z}{2} × \sin(-Q) - F × \sin(γ - Q),
$$
$$
α - \frac{π}{2} ≤ γ ≤ 0
$$

### And when $P > 0$,

$$
x(γ) = \left(P + \frac{Z}{2}\right) × \cos(-γ - Q) - γ × \frac{Z}{2} × \sin(-γ - Q)\\
 - F × \frac{P × \cos(-γ - Q) - γ × \frac{Z}{2} × \sin(-γ - Q)}{\sqrt{P^2 + \left(γ × \frac{Z}{2}\right)^2}},
$$
$$
y(γ) = \left(P + \frac{Z}{2}\right) × \sin(-γ - Q) + γ × \frac{Z}{2} × \cos(-γ - Q)\\
 - F × \frac{P × \sin(-γ - Q) + γ × \frac{Z}{2} × \cos(-γ - Q)}{\sqrt{P^2 + \left(γ × \frac{Z}{2}\right)^2}},
$$
$$
-\frac{2}{Z} × P × \cot(α) ≤ γ ≤ 0
$$

### Where:

- $P := X - C + F$ and
- $Q := \frac{2}{Z} × \left(F × \sec(α) - P × \tan(α) + N × \frac{π}{2}\right)$

### Can these curves be re-written or re-parameterized so that a single set of $(x, y)$ equations covers all three cases?

For example, I've found two different paramterizations of the involute curves:

$$x(θ) = m × \frac{Z}{2} × \cos(α) × \left(\cos\left(θ - \tan(α) + α - N × \frac{π}{Z}\right) + θ × \sin\left(θ - \tan(α) + α - N × \frac{π}{Z}\right)\right),$$
$$y(θ) = m × \frac{Z}{2} × \cos(α) × \left(\sin\left(θ - \tan(α) + α - N × \frac{π}{Z}\right) - θ × \cos\left(θ - \tan(α) + α - N × \frac{π}{Z}\right)\right),$$
$$\frac{2}{Z} × \csc(α) × \left(\frac{F}{\tan(α) + \sec(α)} + \sec(α) × (X - C)\right) + \tan(α) ≤ θ ≤ \sec(α) × \sqrt{(1 + \frac{2}{Z} × (X + 1))^2 - \cos(α)^2}$$

and

$$x(θ) = m × \frac{Z}{2} × \cos(α) × \left(\cos(α + θ) + \sin(α + θ) × \left(\tan(α) + θ + N × \frac{π}{Z}\right)\right),$$
$$y(θ) = m × \frac{Z}{2} × \cos(α) × \left(\sin(α + θ) - \cos(α + θ) × \left(\tan(α) + θ + N × \frac{π}{Z}\right)\right),$$
$$\frac{4}{Z} × \csc(2 × α) × (X - C - F × \sin(α) + F - \sin(2 × α) × N × \frac{π}{4}) ≤ θ ≤ \sqrt{\left(\sec(α) × \left(\frac{2}{Z} × (X + 1) + 1\right)\right)^2 - 1} - \tan(α) - N × \frac{π}{Z}$$

Both sets of equations produce the same involute curve. That suggests to me that it might be possible to re-parameterize the fillet equations to make them equivalent, but I can't figure out how to go about doing that. Is such a thing actually possible?

## Background

I am working on parametrically defining the shape of an [involute gear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute_gear), which consists of many identical copies of four curves:

- two different circular arcs (the tips and roots of the teeth, orange in the picture below),
- an [involute of a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute#Involutes_of_a_circle) (the faces of the teeth, purple), and
- a [roulette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette_(curve)) (joins the involute curve to the root arc as a [fillet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fillet_(mechanics)), blue).

[image: Picture of a GeoGebra file showing an involute gear tooth profile with four curves highlighted.]

All of the above curves are developed as the envelope of [a cutting tool called a hob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbing) that is rotated and translated relative to the gear (in real-life practice the gear blank is typically rotated while the hob profile is translated, but mathematically it seemed simpler to keep the gear entirely stationary by working within its rotating reference frame). The shape of the hob consists of straight line segments for the tooth faces, tips, and roots, and circular arcs for the tip fillets (which become the root fillets on the gear).

[image: Picture of a GeoGebra file showing a hob profile for cutting an involute gear.]

[image: Animated GIF of a GeoGebra file showing a hob profile tracing out an involute gear profile.]

There are four parameters that define the shape of a hob:

- Module $m$, a uniform scale factor that gives the height of the teeth on a generated gear;
- Pitch Angle $α$ (a.k.a. Pressure Angle), the angle of force transfer between meshed gear teeth and the angle of the hob's main cutting faces relative to the normal;
- Clearance Factor $C$, a multiple of the module that extends the tip of the hob's cutting teeth to cut deeper roots than mathematically-necessary on generated gears, reducing friction and allowing mechanical clearance space for coolant/lubricant; and
- Fillet Radius $F$, a multiple of the module that rounds off the corners of the clearance-height on the cutting teeth to give a smoother transition between a generated gear's tooth faces and roots, increasing the strength of the teeth.

When cutting a gear with a hob, there are two additional parameters to consider:

- Profile Shift $X$, a multiple of the module that indicates moving the hob closer to or farther from a generated gear's central axis when cutting, which allows for adjusting the distance between the centers of meshed gears and/or reducing undercutting; and
- Number of Teeth $Z$ (hopefully self-explanatory).

Finally, the parameter $N$ is an integer that simply rotates the equations around the gear body to produce each distinct tooth.

*Undercutting* occurs when the various parameters of a gear are such that the roulette fillet curve on a gear's teeth cuts off part of the involute face curve. Because only the involute curves transfer force between gears, loosing a part of the involute reduces the overall strength of the gear. Small amounts of undercutting are often tolerated, but large amounts are generally to be avoided.

I developed the fillet curves by finding the path traced by the centerpoint of the circular arcs on the hob as the hob-rotation parameter $β$ varied, finding the normal line of that path at the centerpoint, and finding the intersection of that normal line with the circle of radius $m F$ centered on the centerpoint.

For $P < 0$, the path makes a little self-intersecting smooth loop, and the fillet curve uses the positive square root:

[image: Image of Case 1]

For $P > 0$, the path goes around a smooth (if very tight) rounded corner with no self-intersections, and the fillet curve uses the negative square root:

[image: Image of Case 3]

But for the in-between case, when $P ≟ 0$, the curve has a singularity where it instantaneously changes direction, and the fillet curve is a perfect circular arc:

[image: Image of Case 2]

Comment: As w/your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4763518/409), chunking helps. (Wrting $v$ for $\gamma$ ...) Defining $P:=F+X-C$, $Q:= \frac12Zv+...+\frac12N\pi$, $R:=\sqrt{P^2+Q^2}$, $t:=\arctan{P/Q}$, your 1st and 3rd sets of eqns reduce to
$$(x,y) \;=\;\frac12mZ(\cos v,\sin v)\;+\;m(R\pm F)(\cos(v-t),\sin(v-t))$$
(Note the obvious single sign change.) I believe the formatting is faulty on your 2nd set, so I can't say what happens there. ... BTW: It's worth noting that by adding-and-subtracting a convenient $F$, we can write
$$Q = \frac12(Zv+ N\pi)-P\tan\alpha+F\sec\alpha$$

Comment: @Blue What part of the second set of equation seems off to you? I've looked over it and don't see any problems, but that could just mean I'm seeing what I expect to see.

Comment: Other eqns feature $\sin\gamma$ and $\cos\gamma$. I guess I was simply thrown by the 2nd set's trigs of the long $XCF$ expression, as if you inadvertently converted a coefficient into an argument. But, I suppose that expression is as much an "angle" as $\gamma$, so nevermind. ... In any case, it would *really* help if you'd make an effort to "chunkify" your eqns. Repeating expansive sub-expressions over and over makes everything *exceedingly* (and *unnecessarily*) hard to parse. It's in your best interest to minimize a question's "cognitive friction", especially with eqns. ... Good luck!

Comment: @Blue I'll try to work on "chunking" my equations in the future. Hopefully it won't be too hard to learn to do it as thoroughly as you seem to be able to.

Comment: @Blue I did catch a sign error in the second set ("+N" instead of "-N"). I've fixed that and applied some of the chunking you suggested, but I haven't figured out how the $t := \arctan\left(\frac{P}{Q}\right)$ substitution works.

Comment: Whoops ... I should've written $t:=\arctan(Q/P)$. So, along with $R:=\sqrt{P^2+Q^2}$, this gives you $P=R\cos t$ and $Q=R\sin t$, so that $$\begin{align}P\cos\gamma+Q \sin\gamma = R\cos(\gamma-t) \\ P\sin\gamma-Q\cos\gamma = R\sin(\gamma-t)\end{align}$$ and the 1st and 3rd parameterizations reduce as in my first comment. (See also my comments to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4763518/409).) BTW: The long arguments in the 2nd parameterization are "simply" $\gamma-2Q/Z$.

Comment: @Blue I'm still not able to get the $t$ substitutions working. While experimenting in WolframAlpha I noticed that it said the expressions were valid when both $P$ and $Q$ are positive, but for a good portion of the input space in my project, $P$ is actually negative. Would that be enough to throw it off, or am I making a mistake somewhere else?

Comment: If $P$ (which I'm associating with $\cos t$) is negative, then $t$ needs to be a 2nd or 3rd Quadrant angle (according as $Q$ is positive or negative); since $arctan$ returns only 1st and 4th Quadrant angles, you have to fiddle with the outputs to get the appropriate values in all cases. Perhaps a better suggestion is to use $\operatorname{atan2}(Q,P)$ (... or is it $(P,Q)$?), which automates the fiddling. Give that a try.

Comment: @Blue It seems like $t = \operatorname{atan2}(Q, P)$ works. It doesn't seem to get me any closer to a solution, though.

Comment: Well, chunkification makes clear that the only difference between the first and third parameterizations is a single sign change corresponding to $X$ being less-than or greater-than a value; so, that's relatively straightforward to accommodate. The second parameterization is so very different that finding a common form with the others may be too much to ask. But this could be a failure of imagination on my part. ... ("Extended discussion" warning. This may be my last comment on this issue.) ...  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\newcommand{\cis}{\operatorname{cis}}$$

Using these substitutions ...

$$Z_2 := Z/2 \qquad M := \gamma Z_2 \qquad N := \sqrt{P^2+M^2}$$
$$\theta := \operatorname{atan2}(M,P) \quad\to\quad
P = N\cos\theta \qquad M = N\sin\theta$$
$$\cis x := (\cos x, \sin x)$$

... the triad of equations for $(x,y)$ become ...

$$\begin{align}
P < 0: \quad & Z_2\cis(-Q+\gamma) 
\;+\; F \cis(-Q+\gamma-\theta) 
\;+\; N \cis(-Q+\gamma-\theta) \\
P = 0: \quad & Z_2 \cis(-Q\phantom{0\gamma}\;\;) 
\;-\; F \cis(-Q+\gamma \phantom{+\theta}\;\;) \\
P > 0: \quad & Z_2\cis(-Q-\gamma)
\;-\; F \cis(-Q-\gamma+\theta) 
\;+\; N \cis(-Q-\gamma+\theta) 
\end{align} \tag0$$

(I'm ignoring the domain restrictions, which [OP's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4775970/409) handles well enough.)

Defining $\sigma := \operatorname{sgn}(P)$, the $Z_2$ and $N$ terms of these expressions fairly clearly unify as

$$Z_2 \cis(-Q-\sigma\gamma) 
\;+\; N \sigma^2 \cis(-Q-\sigma(\gamma-\theta)) \tag1$$

Unfortunately, the signs in the $F$ terms don't correlate as nicely with the sign of $P$. Perhaps the best we might do —as OP has done— is to combine the terms as-is, folding the cases together using coefficients that evaluate to either $1$ or $0$:

$$-F \; (\; 
\underbrace{\sigma \cis(-Q - \sigma (\gamma - \theta))}_{\text{ignored when $P=\sigma=0$}}
\;+\; \underbrace{(1 - \sigma^2) \cis(-Q + \gamma)}_{\text{ignored when $P\neq0, \; \sigma=\pm1$}}\;) \tag2$$

So, combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ unifies the equations. This is effectively OP's result, streamlined a bit with $N$, $\theta$, and the "$\cis$" shorthand.

As an alternative to $(2)$, suppose we define
$$\sigma_+ = \begin{cases}\phantom{-}1, & P \geq 0 \\ -1, &P<0 \end{cases} \qquad
\sigma_- = \begin{cases}\phantom{-}1, & P > 0 \\ -1, &P\leq0\end{cases}$$
(Think of the subscript as assigning that sign to zero.) With these, the $F$ terms have this common form:

$$- F\sigma_+ \cis(-Q-\sigma_-\gamma+\sigma\theta) \tag3$$

In fact, since the $N$ term of $(1)$ vanishes for $\sigma=0$, and $\sigma_-=\sigma$ when $\sigma\neq0$, the argument of the $F$ term can be used for the $N$ term. So, we can write the combined equations as

$$Z_2 \cis(-Q-\sigma\gamma) \;+\; (N \sigma^2 - F\sigma_+) \cis(-Q-\sigma_-\gamma+\sigma\theta) \tag4$$

Even so, the use of $\sigma_\pm$ may be trying a bit *too* hard to fold all of the cases together. But, then again, $(2)$ is also rather artificial. Only in $(1)$ does the sign trichotomy integrate somewhat naturally with the expressions.

Comment: Your combination of (1) and (2) works almost perfectly. The only issue is that the software I'm using doesn't like when the curve-drawing-parameter is hidden inside other variables. I submitted an edit adding the best version of the expression that I've been able to come up with (so far) that takes this into account.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a rather messy solution using many instances of $\operatorname{sgn}(P)$:

$$
x(γ) =  \left(P + \frac{Z}{2}\right) × \cos(\operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ + Q) + \operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ × \frac{Z}{2} × \sin(\operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ + Q) \\
- \operatorname{sgn}(P) × F × \frac{P × \cos(\operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ + Q) + \operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ × \frac{Z}{2} × \sin(\operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ + Q)}{\sqrt{P^2 + \left(γ × \frac{Z}{2}\right)^2}} \\
- (1 - \operatorname{sgn}(P)^2) × F × \cos(γ - Q),
$$
$$
y(γ) = -\left(P + \frac{Z}{2}\right) × \sin(\operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ + Q) + \operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ × \frac{Z}{2} × \cos(\operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ + Q) \\
+ \operatorname{sgn}(P) × F × \frac{P × \sin(\operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ + Q) - \operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ × \frac{Z}{2} × \cos(\operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ + Q)}{\sqrt{P^2 + \left(γ × \frac{Z}{2}\right)^2}} \\
- (1 - \operatorname{sgn}(P)^2) × F × \sin(γ - Q),
$$
$$
(1 - \operatorname{sgn}(P)^2) × \left(α - \frac{π}{2}\right) - \operatorname{abs}(P) × \frac{2}{Z} × \cot(α) ≤ γ ≤ 0
$$

When $P ≟ 0$, $\operatorname{sgn}(P) ≟ 0$ and all the terms multiplied by $\operatorname{sgn}(P)$ vanish, reducing the equations to the second case. In contrast, the term $(1 - \operatorname{sgn}(P)^2)$ equals zero for all values of $P$ ***except*** $P ≟ 0$, so terms multiplied by $(1 - \operatorname{sgn}(P)^2)$ vanish whenever $P ≠ 0$, reducing the equations to the first or third case.

It isn't very pretty or elegant, but it works.

***If anyone has suggestions for how to clean it up, please leave a comment!***

EDIT: For practical reasons, I want to keep gamma outside of other variables. Based on @Blue's answer, I was able to refine the separate $x$ and $y$ equations to the following complex-valued $z = x + y × i$ form:
$$
z(γ) = \left(\frac{Z}{2} + \left(P + \operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ × \frac{Z}{2} × i\right) \left(1 - \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(P) × F}{\sqrt{P^2 + \left(γ × \frac{Z}{2}\right)^2}}\right)\right) \\
× \operatorname{cis}(-\operatorname{sgn}(P) × γ - Q) - (1 - \operatorname{sgn}(P)^2) × F × \operatorname{cis}(γ - Q)
$$

where $\operatorname{cis}(x) = \cos(x) + \sin(x) × i$.